# How a metaclass singleton works

Tags: python, singleton, super

It's not clear to me how [the typical metaclass singleton implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) works.  I would expect the starred print to execute twice; it only happens once:

```py
class _Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Within __call__', cls, cls._instances, *args, **kwargs)
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            print('**About to call __call__', super(_Singleton, cls).__call__, flush=True)
            print("Is cls the '...of object'?", hex(id(cls)).upper())
            cls._instances[cls] = super(_Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            print(cls._instances[cls])
        return cls._instances[cls]


class MySingleton(metaclass=_Singleton):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Making mysingleton')
    mysingleton = MySingleton()
    print("Is mysingleton the 'cls'?", mysingleton)

    print('Making another')
    another = MySingleton()

    # Verify singletude
    assert another == mysingleton
```

This prints

```
Making mysingleton
Within __call__ <class '__main__.MySingleton'> {}
**About to call __call__ <method-wrapper '__call__' of _Singleton object at 0x000001C950C28780>
Is cls the '...of object'? 0X1C950C28780
<__main__.MySingleton object at 0x000001C9513FCA30>
Is mysingleton the 'cls'? <__main__.MySingleton object at 0x000001C9513FCA30>
Making another
Within __call__ <class '__main__.MySingleton'> {<class '__main__.MySingleton'>: <__main__.MySingleton object at 0x000001C9513FCA30>}
```

As is my experience with the Python docs, they're terribly circular and confusing.  The docs say that `__call__()` is called when an instance is "called".  Fair enough; `MySingleton.__call__` is run because the "()" on `mysingleton = MySingleton()` indicates a function call.  MySingleton is of the _Singleton type, so it has an _instances dict.  The dict is naturally empty on first call.  The conditional fails and `Super(_Singleton, cls).__call__` executes.

What does super() do here?  It's barely intelligible from the docs.  It returns a "proxy object", explained elsewhere as "an object which 'refers' to a shared object", that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of 'type'.  Okay, fine; it will be used to call a method of some related _Singleton type.

The two argument form of super(), which is used here, "specifies the arguments exactly and makes the appropriate references".  What references are those?  The type is `_Singleton` and object is cls, which isn't `mysingleton`.  It's whatever object `0x000001C950C28780` is.  Anyway, the super() search order is that of `getattr()` or `super()`.  I think that means references are looked up according to `_Singleton.__mro__` since `__call__` isn't an attribute (or is it?).  That is, the super() call looks up according to super(), which I assume is _Singleton.  Clear as mud.   The `__mro__` yields `(<class '__main__._Singleton'>, <class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)`.  So, `super(_Singleton, cls)` will look for the "related _Singleton type" and call its `__call__` method; I assume that's `cls.__call__()`.

Since cls is a _Singleton, I would expect to see the second print.  Actually, I would expect some kind of recursion.  Neither happen.  What's going on in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `super` builtin is not the most simple thing in Python syntax. It is used when a method has been overriden in a hierarchy of classes and allows to specify indirectly which version (the method defined in which ancestor class) will actually be called.

Here, `_Singleton` is a subclass of `type`. Fair enough. But as the `__call__` method of `_Singleton` has been overriden, it will have to call the same method **in its parent class** to actually build an object. That is the purpose of `super(_Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)`: it will forward the call to the parent of `_Singleton`. So it is the same as:

```
type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

That is: it call the `__call__` method **of `type`** but still uses `cls` as a `self` object allowing the creation a `MySingleton` object and bypassing a recursive call to `_Singleton.__call__`. Alternatives would be to use `S.__new__(S, *args, **kwargs)` or directly `object.__new__(S)`, but that last one would bypass any possible object initialization.

In fact, `super` is the Pythonic way here, because if you later build a more complex hierarchy of metaclasses (_Singleton <- _GenericMeta <- type), `super(_Singleton, cls)` will ensure to use the class immediately preceding `_Singleton` in the hierachy.

Comment: That clarifies what `super()` resolves to and how it avoids recursion.  So then what does `type.__call__` actually do?  The manual says "There are no special operations on types."  I see that `type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` returns  `<__main__.MySingleton object at 0x000001C9513FCA30>`.  I notice this is the same result as `type(cls.__name__, (), {})`.  Does type just make a new type with the name of whatever object is passed to it?

Comment: I see that `type.__call__` is a `<slot wrapper '__call__' of 'type' objects>`.  That looks like a wrapper for whatever implementation is written in C.

Comment: @LoremIpsum: Beware. `type(cls.__name__, (), {})` builds a class while `type.__call__(cls)` builds an instance of `cls`.